# ASP.NET Connection loss handling

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, error-handling

How would you go about and handle lost data from a sql connection loss on a ASP.NET application.

Lets say your running an algorithm adding and removing certain roles. A midst it, the connection to the SQL database is lost. And because the connection is not there, wont even be able to backtrack the steps done. The whole state is lost, leaving the database in an error nous condition.

Would you set the IIS Rapid Fail Protection to shut the site down upon 1 exception and manually force the function to run again (after connection have been fixed).

Or how is the professional way of handling it, i am quite new to it. Maybe there's something i do not know of it (such as iis maybe trying to rerun it/caching)

(Using entity framework)

This is not a coding problem in its own way, it is more of a question of best practice handling data loss with sql database on asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do batch SQL Operations inside a SQL Transaction. So that whatever the error, a rollback happens. This is a built-in SQL feature and nothing special needs to be done.

Once you start a SQL Transaction, a Commit is issued only when all operations succeed. The default behavior is normally Rollback in case of all other non-success scenarios.

If you're encountering issues with any specific logic, post the code snippet and we're glad to help.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess i never really thought about it, but deep down knew, but the thinking really just occurred when i was creating a group management for the new Identity in ASP.NET. Im going to assume thoose actually commit everytime you change a roles, so would have to make my own function instead.. i guess the userstore, not used it alot, mainly just the usermanager :) thanks